# Unknown space, not margin nor padding

Tags: html, css

What is the space between html elements that appears even when the margin and padding are set to 0, and how do I get rid of it?

Run the following code snippet and notice the space between the elements:

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.button-label, .tab-label {
  display:inline-block;
  background: #eee; 
  border: 1px solid;
}
[name="tab-group-1"] {
  display: none;  
}
```

```html
Example 1:
<div class="button-container">
       <button class="button-label">Button One</button>
       <button class="button-label">Button Two</button>
       <button class="button-label">Button Three</button>
</div>
Example 2:
<div class="radio-container">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked>
       <label class="tab-label" for="tab-1">Tab One</label>
       <input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1">
       <label class="tab-label" for="tab-2">Tab Two</label>
       <input type="radio" id="tab-3" name="tab-group-1">
       <label class="tab-label" for="tab-3">Tab Three</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Here's a [`good read`](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) on the subject, if you're interested. Features multiple solutions for it. I recommend `flexbox`.

Comment: Thanks. I normally would use flexbox, but I'm working on a challenge where I'm trying to create a responsive tab container that accordions down (without using positioning) and using only html and css (no JS) and the only way I can find to do that is to put the inputs and the content next to eachother under the same parent div. If I were to wrap the input buttons in another div so that I could make it a flexbox, then I wouldn't be able to reference `#button-1:focus ~ #content-1{display:"flex"}` to show content. And if I use flex on the parent, the content will be treated just like the buttons.

Comment: Well, since you mentioned `responsive`, you should notice `font-size: 0` is really bad for mobile devices, but you got plenty other options to choose from. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

The space can be difficult to diagnose initially because it is not highlighted by browser inspectors, but once you know that it is a result of white-space (new-lines) in your html in-between your html tags, then handling the problem is quite simple. 
You have one of several options to remove the space including the following:

1. Either, remove that white space between your tags in your html. (Unfortunately, that makes your html messier, so the second option may be better.)
2. Or, in your css, set the font-size in the parent container to 0px ( ex: `#parent{font-size:0px;}` ), and then initialize it again for all the children of the parent (with something like `#parent *{font-size:initial;}` ). Note: This solution may require you to specify again some of the child font-sizes if they had been modified earlier in your css flow.

Here's an Example: (notice the space has been removed)

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#button-container, #radio-container{
  font-size:0px;
  display:block;
}
#button-container *, #radio-container *{
  font-size:initial;
}
.button-label, .tab-label {
  display:inline-block;
  background: #eee; 
  border: 1px solid;
}
[name="tab-group-1"] {
  display: none;  
}
```

```html
Example 1:
<div id="button-container">
       <button class="button-label">Button One</button>
       <button class="button-label">Button Two</button>
       <button class="button-label">Button Three</button>
</div>
Example 2:
<div id="radio-container">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked>
       <label class="tab-label" for="tab-1">Tab One</label>
       <input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1">
       <label class="tab-label" for="tab-2">Tab Two</label>
       <input type="radio" id="tab-3" name="tab-group-1">
       <label class="tab-label" for="tab-3">Tab Three</label>
</div>
```